# How can I change a dataframe to a simple dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, transform, apply, correlation

I made a corr data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        [10,15,20,25,50,55,60],
        [20,50,1,4,29,351,1],
        [-1,-20,-30,-45,-50,-55,-70]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, index = ['a','b','c','d']).T
corr = df.corr(method = 'pearson')
print(corr)

          a         b         c         d  
a  1.000000  0.966282  0.347232 -0.983120  
b  0.966282  1.000000  0.414710 -0.917002  
c  0.347232  0.414710  1.000000 -0.247203  
d -0.983120 -0.917002 -0.247203  1.000000
```

I want to change like this by apply method.

```
a a 1.000000  
a b 0.966282  
a c 0.347232  
a d 0.983120  
b a 0.966282  
b b 1.000000  
....
```

How can I transform this dataframe using apply function?

Comment: Why do you _have_ to use `apply`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.unstack()` with `reset_index`:

```
corr.unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   level_0 level_1         0
0        a       a  1.000000
1        a       b  0.966282
2        a       c  0.347232
3        a       d -0.983120
4        b       a  0.966282
5        b       b  1.000000
6        b       c  0.414710
7        b       d -0.917002
8        c       a  0.347232
9        c       b  0.414710
10       c       c  1.000000
11       c       d -0.247203
12       d       a -0.983120
13       d       b -0.917002
14       d       c -0.247203
15       d       d  1.000000
```

Comment: But I met an error like this.
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (45852, 45852) and data type float64

Comment: how can i use this on huge data?

Comment: In such a case, you are trying to make 2 _billion_ rows of dataframe. What is your next step? what do you intend to do after `unstack`ing the `corr`?

Comment: So you want to keep rows that have all elements greater than 0.8?

Comment: I only want to leave more than 0.8 data. like this. 'corr['corr'] = corr['corr'].apply(lambda x: x if x > 0.8 else np.nan)'
and then 'corr= corr.dropna(axis=0)'

Comment: Try `corr = corr.where(corr.gt(0.8), np.nan).dropna(axis=0)` and then do the `unstack`.

Comment: that's right. It seems to be a problem because of the large data size.